# symfony/validator: how to validate string as int

Tags: php, symfony, postman, symfony-validator

I created a contoller in Symfony that will be handle API requests. I want to validate action request. Parameter 'type' of the request must be **integer**. There is controller action code:

```
public function store(ValidatorInterface $validator, Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $collection = new Collection([
        'type' => [
            new Assert\Type('int'),
            new Assert\Range(['min' => 1, 'max' => 2])
        ]
    ]);

    $errors = $validator->validate($request->request->all(), $collection);
    if ($errors->count()) {
        dd($errors);
    }

    return new JsonResponse('OK');
}
```

But when I tested this action via Postman, validation is failed with error **"This value should be of type int."** event if I send response with int value:

[image: my response]

What is the right way to validate int param or string param as int in Symfony?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem is that `form-data` sends everything as strings (I might be wrong). But one way to overcome this would be to send `json`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `digit` type for the type validator. Then the validator will check type via [ctype_digit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) function

```
new Assert\Type('digit'),
```